# Hiding HighCharts StackLabels when series is large

Tags: javascript, highcharts

there are a few questions about stacklables on SO, but I don't see any related to my question.

Right now, I have a pretty standard column chart (built with HighCharts). It has basic stack labels and everything works fine. However, when a user expands the viewset of the data (in essence expanding the size of the series) the StackLabels (labels above individual columns) overlap and look messy.

So, I want to hide the stack labels for all columns when the series is say >= 20.

Right now, my stack labels are shown like this:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'My Title'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                //if more than 20 points, hide them
                if (this.series.length >= 20) { 
                        return ''
                 }
                //else show them 
                return this.total
        }
    },
```

But this doesn't work because the context for 'this' isnt correct, thus this.series.[anything] returns undefined. It seems 'this' is referring to the point..but I need to reference the chart that contains the point.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you add  fiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This* in the formatter does not refer to the chart object nor the axis. Also, data from the series is not yet available. However, you can get the length of the data from the options.

```
      formatter: function() {
    //if more than 20 points, hide them
    if (this.axis.series[0].options.data.length >= 20) {
      return false
    }
    //else show them 
    return this.total
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6mmLu3ct/